# Change CSS in an iframe with obfuscated classes

Tags: javascript, html, css, class, iframe

I need to change css of elements inside on an iframe but their classes are obfuscated, every time I call iframe, class names are differents, I was trying with **jquery** like **$('div table td')** but it's and external iframe so It doesnt read those elements, any help would we awesome! [See obfuscated classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9gV7.png)

Comment: You cannot change styles from an external iframe

Comment: Okey I see, thanks!